# Yarn freezes after building packages inside docker

Tags: docker, startup, yarnpkg

I have to have my js app ready on docker whenever my google cloud instance starts up. I have a startup script that builds the docker images, and starts up the container.

However, I have noticed that my `yarn install` process freezes for about 4-5 minutes. It freezes after it's `building fresh packages` stage.

I am using a 7.5gb memory, a 20gb disk machine.

To build multiple images in parallel, I execute the docker commands in the background, for example:

`nohup docker-compose build web &>logs/web.txt &`

Here's an example dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}
RUN mkdir -p /home/project
RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
WORKDIR /home/project
COPY local-project/ /home/project/
RUN /usr/sbin/adduser node sudo
RUN chown -R node /usr/local/
RUN chown -R node /usr/bin/
RUN chown -R node /home/project
USER node
RUN yarn global add forever
RUN yarn install --ignore-engines
EXPOSE 1337
```

I am thinking of trying out with an instance with higher ram, but I would like to know if there is something wrong with what I have already got going in here.

Comment: Can you pre-build the image and push it to a repository, like Google’s GCR?  That’s a more standard deployment workflow than re-running the build every single time.

Comment: Images would be built based on specific repo branches that a user would select, so I can't have prebuilt images.